# How to align the content of this table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, enumitem, makecell

I'm struggling with the alignment of the content of this table. I want that the content of each cell of the first column to be centered vertically or at least to remove the white space at the top of the two other columns. I've tried with the `array` package but with no success. Can someone help?

Of course, here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{tablelist}{itemize}{3}
\setlist[tablelist,1]{label={--},leftmargin=1em, nosep}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering 
    \begin{tabular}{m{8em} p{14em} p{14em} }
    \hline
     \textbf{Col A} & \textbf{Col B} & \textbf{Col C} \\
    \hline \hline
     \textbf{\makecell[l]{Extremely \\ long title}} &
    \begin{tablelist}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
        \item Item 4
        \item Item 5
    \end{tablelist} &
    \begin{tablelist}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{tablelist} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \\
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

I want to point out that this is a single row of the table I'll need to code, and I prefer not to use `multirow`. Moreover, I've exploited `\makecell` because I just want to control when the text of each cell in Col A goes to the following line.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

If I correctly Understood you, than you are after something like this:

[image]

This table form is simple to get with use of the `tabularray` package with libraries `booktabs` (fir table rules) and `varwidth`(for list spacing):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tablelist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tablelist,1]{nosep,
    leftmargin=*,
    label=--,
    before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\raggedright,
    after =\end{minipage}
                    }
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[l, m, wd=8em, font=\bfseries] 
                            X[l,h]  X[l,h]},
                row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                measure=vbox,
                }
    \toprule
Col A   &   Col B   &   Col C       \\
    \midrule
{Extremely \\ long title}
    &   \begin{tablelist}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \item Item 5
        \end{tablelist} &   \begin{tablelist}
                        \item Item 1
                        \item Item 2
                            \end{tablelist} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can delete the `\centering`.

Comment: Yes, that's the desired output nevertheless, I am using Texpad with internal Typesetter, and `tabularray` is not supported. At the moment, I would avoid switching to the PdfLaTeX typesetter, but if no other workaround exists I'll consider switching to it.

Comment: @F.Pantigny, you are right. I forgot to delete it after first attempt when I try to use OP defined column width and then observe, that table is to wide. So I change `Q` type to `X` column type ... Corrected now.

Comment: @polmdm, as far as I know Texpad is an editor and have nothing with your LaTeX installation. You only need to install `tabularray` package (by help of utility which is part of LaTeX installation bundle).

Comment: That's true, but it features an internal LaTeX installation that compiles in real-time and it's way faster than common ones (20x). The drawback is that it does not have all the functions and packages, and sometimes, I am forced to find some workaround, like in this case

Comment: @polmdm, really? This is the first time that I hear that the translation speed depends on used editor.

Comment: @Zarko I am definitely not a Pro user of LaTeX, so I am having a hard time understanding and explaining how it works. However, TexPad let you choose how to compile the document. Either you use the internal Typesetter (TexpadTex) that has some pros in terms of speed and installation, or you use an external typesetter like MacTex, and then you choose the compiler engine (pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LaTex>dvips>ps2pdf...). Probably, due to some optimization, the internal typesetter takes a couple of seconds to compile the document, compared to the 20 sec of the other typesetters.

Answer (score 0):

With `nicematrix` (≥ 6.14 of 2023/02/18):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tablelist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tablelist,1]{leftmargin=*,label=--,nosep,after = \vspace{-1em}}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}w{l}{8em}X[l]X[l]}
\toprule
\RowStyle[bold]{}
Col A   &   Col B   &   Col C    \\
\midrule
\Block[v-center]{}{Extremely long~title}
& 
\begin{tablelist}
    \item Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \item Item 5
\end{tablelist}
&
\begin{tablelist}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
\end{tablelist} \\
\Block[v-center]{}{Extremely long~title}
& 
\begin{tablelist}
    \item Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 Item 1 
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
    \item Item 5
\end{tablelist}
&
\begin{tablelist}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
\end{tablelist} \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]